# MySQL: Localhost No Connection

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE at Windows 10.

After using this it for about half a year from now, suddenly I can't connect in my localhost.

I tried to Start it in `services.msc`, message that

`The MySQL57 service on Local Computer started and the stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs`.

I also tried to Restart in `Start/Shutdown MySQL Server`, message logs:

```
`
2016-03-05T08:56:45.676977Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2016-03-05T08:56:45.676977Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2016-03-05T08:56:46.181026Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2016-03-05T08:56:46.884128Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-03-05T08:56:48.040716Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-03-05T08:56:48.165738Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.446971Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.446971Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.462594Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.462594Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.462594Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.540743Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.572049Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.587618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-03-05T08:56:48.993929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-03-05T08:56:48.993929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-03-05T08:56:54.185228Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2016-03-05T08:56:54.358962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 160305 16:56:54
2016-03-05T08:57:00.648800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 6320654
2016-03-05T08:57:00.764536Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-03-05T08:57:00.764536Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-03-05T08:57:00.780108Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-03-05T08:57:00.780108Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-03-05T08:57:00.780108Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-03-05T08:57:00.780108Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
`
```

I don't know what to do next.. :(

Please somebody advise what to do. Thanks!

Comment: The log only contains the shutdown sequence, much more interesting would be the startup sequence. Probably something changed that keep it from starting (corrupt data?).

Comment: @MikeLischke, how will I know that?

Comment: Try starting the server and look in the error log.